# Eliminate Portion of String in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string

Lets say I have a variable: varEmail. It contains a variable equal to the user's email address, so it might contain a value like:

> "myemail@emailserver.com"

Now, lets say I want to get just a portion of the email address, e.g. strip off the domain, like so:

> "myemail"

How can I accomplish this in VB.NET with string manipulation? I know this must be simple...maybe it is just early in the morning...

Comment: Surprised nobody mentioned regex-replacing `@.*$` with an empty string yet!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one gives the email name; the second gives the domain name.

```
dim varEmail as string="myemail@emailserver.com"
MsgBox(varEmail.Substring(0, varEmail.IndexOf("@")))
MsgBox(varEmail.Substring(varEmail.IndexOf("@") + 1))
```

Answer (score 4):

If you know you are always dealing with valid email addresses, the easiest way might be as so:

```
varEmail = varEmail.Split("@"c)(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

For the fun of it, here is a more old school approach that still works in .Net (and like Matt's answer, this assumes you know this is a valid E-mail Address)...

```
strResult = Mid(varEmail, 1, (InStr(varEmail, "@") - 1))
```

If you aren't sure you have a valid e-mail do this in a try catch (it will throw an exception if the e-mail is not valid)...

```
Dim objMail As New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(varEmail)
strResult = objMail.User
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Split method. For example:

```
Dim MyString As String = "myemail@emailserver.com"
Dim MyString2() As String
Dim MyString3 As String

MyString2 = Split(MyString, "@", -1, CompareMethod.Binary)
MyString3 = MyString2(0)
```

Now MyString3 = myemail

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for your problem:

```
Dim value, result as string

     value="myemail@emailserver.com"
       result = value.Substring(0, value.IndexOf('@')+1)
```

I hope this will help you out.

Comment: No... I didn't... I am a C# programmer. I just wrote the code and modified according to VB.NET

Comment: Well apart from the fact that you *haven't* modified it to work with VB.NET - even after modification it gives the wrong result as requested by the OP. If you are a C# programmer who is not that familiar with VB.NET it is probably best to stick to questions tagged C#. Try this: `result = value.Substring(0, value.IndexOf("@"))`